# Remove inset of tableView inside a StackView with fixed layout margins

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have a StackView with fixed layout margins to give a margin on the left and the right for all child elements. This works great for most of the child elements like Labels etc. However, I have also a tableView as a child which gets then an additional inset for the cells (e.g. subtitle prototype), and the searchbar. How can I remove the inset only for the table view?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The space that you see is added by UITableViewCell of type "SubTitle".

You can create a custom `UITableViewCell`, have the Leading Edge set to the same of the ContentView.
[image]

Comment: Ok thanks that did it for the UITableViewCell, but how can I get the SearchBar bigger? Ideally the search icon would be at the same x position than the text, like it is now

Comment: That should not be a problem (doesn't look bad), as the light gray area spacing is provided by UISearchBar icon. But if you want that with zero offset too (you will lose many advantages of UISearchBar components ex: scope buttons).Create a UITextField and set an icon on the left side, using UITextField.leftView.